# Different Text Rendering Methods Don't Produce The One I Want

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, gdi

I am looking for a text rendering method where a graphics object is initialized from a bitmap, text is drawn on it and the text looks like the first line in the attached image.

Can someone please explain a method that will do this? I'm not fully understanding why none of the following methods can reproduce it:

Font in test is: Segoe UI, 8.25pt

```
protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    //drawing the string with the Graphics object the form gives us
    e.Graphics.DrawString("1. This is a test using DrawString. " + e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint.ToString(), 
                          base.Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 10));

    //width used for all images
    const int width = 300;

    //drawing the string with Graphics objects initialized from bitmaps
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, 20);
    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.DrawString("2. This is a test using DrawString. " + gfx.TextRenderingHint.ToString(), 
                       base.Font, Brushes.Black, Point.Empty);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(10, 30));

    bmp.Dispose();
    bmp = new Bitmap(width, 20);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        gfx.DrawString("3. This is a test using DrawString. " + gfx.TextRenderingHint.ToString(), 
                       base.Font, Brushes.Black, Point.Empty);
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(10, 50));

    bmp.Dispose();
    bmp = new Bitmap(width, 20);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        gfx.DrawString("4. This is a test using DrawString. " + gfx.TextRenderingHint.ToString(), 
                       base.Font, Brushes.Black, Point.Empty);
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(10, 70));

    bmp.Dispose();
    bmp = new Bitmap(width, 20);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        gfx.DrawString("5. This is a test using DrawString. " + gfx.TextRenderingHint.ToString(),
                       base.Font, Brushes.Black, Point.Empty);
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(10, 90));

    bmp.Dispose();
    bmp = new Bitmap(width, 20);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            path.AddString("6. This is a test using GraphicsPath. " + gfx.TextRenderingHint.ToString(), 
                           base.Font.FontFamily, (int)base.Font.Style, 
                           base.Font.Size, Point.Empty, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

            gfx.FillPath(Brushes.Black, path);
        }
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(10, 110));

    bmp.Dispose();
    bmp = new Bitmap(width, 20);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            path.AddString("7. This is a test using GraphicsPath. " + gfx.TextRenderingHint.ToString(),
                           base.Font.FontFamily, (int)base.Font.Style,
                           base.Font.Size, Point.Empty, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

            gfx.FillPath(Brushes.Black, path);
        }
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(10, 130));

}
```

[image: Form1_v2]

Comment: Have you tried `TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit`? EDIT: What would happen if you did your "test 4" version but used `TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault` instead?

Comment: +1 Good question I also faced this issue before, but didn't raised a question

Comment: @ChrisSinclair ClearTypeGridFit won't look like it either. SystemDefault is the default value when the graphics object is initialized, it would look like #2.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting _all_ the properties of the incoming `e.Graphics` object (like its `PageUnit`, `SmoothingMode`, `TextContrast`, `InterpolationMode`, etc, to see which values differ between that and the `Graphics` object you get from `Graphics.FromImage(bmp)`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes, and the only one that is different is the PageUnit property (FromImage initializes to Display, Form passes Pixel). Everything else is the same. This is why I am setting the PageUnit property in each test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in your code, you forget to initialize the bitmap.  It will be filled with pixels that are Color.Transparent, black with an alpha of 0.  When you draw the text, Graphics.DrawString() will implement the TextRenderingHint you ask for, anti-aliasing the text.  But the foreground color for the text is black.  And the background color is black.  So the anti-aliasing pixels blend from black to black.  Completely ruining the anti-aliasing effect, it turns the letter shape into a blob.  Fix:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, 20);
using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    gfx.Clear(this.BackColor);
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Thank-you Hans.